# Fill remaining height of min-height, max-height parent

Tags: html, css

I'm have a container which is of height:

```
.contact__user-input {
  max-height: 50vh;
  min-height: 50vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Inside of this container, as the last child, I have a `textarea`. This element is supposed to fill the remaining height - how can I do so?

```
<div class="contact__user-input">
   ...
   <textarea class="contact__textarea separator--small mt-4 w-100" placeholder="Sonstige Leistungen oder eine Nachricht an uns (optional)"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

As you keep adding the data it will keep appending it until it reaches `height:50vh;` then a scroll will be seen.

> View it in full screen for the height variations.

```css
.contact__user-input {
  overflow: scroll;
  min-height: 50vh;
  max-height: 50vh;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact__user-input">
...
  <textarea class="contact__textarea separator--small mt-4 w-100" placeholder="Sonstige Leistungen oder eine Nachricht an uns (optional)"></textarea>
</div>
```